# protractor, loop of elements

Tags: javascript, loops, protractor, cucumber, cucumberjs

I'm new in Protractor. I'm doing automated tests and in my feature file I have this to check:

```
When('there are at least two ports loaded', function (next) { }
```

In my html I have this:

```
<div class="port-element ">
   <div class="image-loader" style="display: inline;">
      <picture> (...) </picture>
```

I'm trying to doing a loop to check this, but maybe I really don't understand how:

```
let port_element = element.all(by.css('port-element '));
      port_element.each(function (item) { 
        console.log('Port element count: ', item);
      });
      next();
```

but I don't understand how.

Under advice I used this on my stepdefinition:

```
let count = await element.all(by.css('.port-element')).count();
for(let i=1;i<=count;i++)
{
  let selector = 'div.port-element div.image-loader:nth-child('+i+')');
  //selector is the element within each div to now check
}
```

and

expect(element.all(by.css('div.port-item div.image-loader')).count()).to.be.above(2)

but I have this error now:

```
AssertionError: expected ManagedPromise::4833 {[[PromiseStatus]]: "pending"} to be a number or a date
```

Now I tried to do like this:

```
let img_loader_count = element.all(by.css('div.port-element div.image-loader'));
    console.log('img loader count: ', img_loader_count.count());
```

but I have this on console:
img loader count: 0

There are 12 img loader count, so this is impossible. Why on console it prints 0?
Can someone help me?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I have seen to do this is using the element.count() to be the index for a loop such as:

```
let count = await element.all(by.css('.port-element')).count();
for(let i=1;i<=count;i++)
{
  let selector = 'div.port-element div.image-loader:nth-child('+i+')');
  //selector is the element within each div to now check
}
```

However, if you are only trying to check that there are a certain number of images that are within the port element, then you can do

```
expect(element.all(by.css('div.port-element div.image-loader').count()).toBe(2);
```

**Per question edit:**
You should be using `expect()` instead of `console.log()`. The asynchronous nature of js can cause weird things to happen when you are trying to log variables like that since it isn't wrapped in a promise. Using `expect(img_loader_count.count()).toBe(12);` should give you the your expected result. If you need to use `console.log()` for whatever reason, you have to properly queue it like:

```
element.all(by.css('div.port-element div.image-loader').count().then(function(value){
  console.log('The count is: '+value);
});
```

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) is the documentation for some of the promise stuff.

Comment: Ben, I don't know why, but now I have this error:
 TypeError: by.css(...).count is not a function

Comment: changing the order of the brackets, it returns this error:
 AssertionError: expected ManagedPromise::4833 {[[PromiseStatus]]: "pending"} to be a number or a date

Comment: @Spicchio Its hard to tell without a good example. If you could either ask a new question or add it to this question I would be happy to help.

Comment: @Spicchio Only use the last part of my answer. The first part answers the technical question of how to loop through elements, but I don't believe it is necessary to solve your problem. I misread the question a bit. They were 2 separate ways to solve the problem, and weren't meant to be used at the same time

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunatly the error is the same that i added on my question:
AssertionError: expected ManagedPromise::4827 {[[PromiseStatus]]: "pending"} to be a number or a date

Comment: Weird. It should be almost the same as Akash's answer, just with a diffrent CSS Selector. Maybe try his syntax but just use `'div.port-element div.image-loader'` for the selector? Im used to jasmine framework so its always possible there is a small syntax error if you straight copy paste. I don't know what changes in cucumber and what is the same

Comment: Hi @Ben Mohorc, I edited my question with updates! Please check it and give me an advice. Thank you

Comment: @Spicchio Hopefully this last answer helps. If you are still having issues, I would consider asking a new question as this is now getting further away from the original question

Answer (score 0):

You can use count() to check how many classes are loaded in the current page.

I have done some minor changes to your code, Hope it'll help you.

```
    let port_element = element.all(by.css('.port-element'));
        expect(port_element.count()).toBe(2);
```

Comment: Thank you Akash, it is ok in this way, but the problem is that I need to understand how to loop these elements. Look, for example the next scenario is this: "I want to see an image on every single port-element", so I have to loop these elements and check the elements inside.
How can I do this? Can you give me an example?